# How to restore XML code style settings in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

File > Settings. After I change rules to languages (spaces, wrappings, imports, etc.) and restart Android Studio, they apply again. But if I change XML settings, they will be lost after restart. So every time after restart of AS I have to change these settings again. How can I make AS to save and restore XML settings?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save XML settings do following.

1. Open Settings: `Ctrl+Alt+S`.
2. Find XML in `Editor > Code Styles > XML`, `Android` tab.
3. Select two checkboxes. Select scheme and press `Copy to Project...`.

[image]

4. Now you can redefine a `Project scheme`. Also check two checkboxes. Now your scheme becomes `Project` with your settings, and after restart you will have this new scheme.

[image]